# Paypal IOS SDK acceptCreditCards crashing

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, paypal-sandbox

There is a very niche question, I have implemented the PayPal ios SDK as they have it in the sample project however when I change the `acceptCreditCards` variable to true. The pay with credit card button shows up however if you click it the app crashes. What other code do I have to add to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some testing I realized that the problem was camera permissions. Paypal needs to use your camera a so you have to put camera permissions in your info.plist. TO do this simply add `$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use` under the key `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`.

Answer (score 0):

Credit card Payment is deprecated after paypal's version 2.15.1